# Jquery datetimepicker without time

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker with format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
Everything is working fine and it don't ask me for the time .
But if I add endDate it start asking me for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
     format:'Y-m-d',
     timepicker:false,
     minDate:'-1970/01/02', //yesterday is minimum date
     maxDate:'+1970/01/02' //tomorrow is maximum date
        });
    });
```

```css
.dt{
  margin-top:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="dt" type="text" id="datetimepicker"/>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
 <script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```